# using NotifyPropertyChange with ReadOnly collections

Tags: wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have a treeView control whose ItemSource is bound to a collection of strings. If I add items to the collection like this

```
private void AddItems()
{
    _myList.Add("string1");
    _myList.Add("string2");
    _myList.Add("string3");
    NotifyOfPropertyChanged(() => MyList);
}
```

My string collection is defined like this

```
private Collection<string> _myList;
public Collection<string> MyList 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return _myList;
    }
}
```

Then nothing get updated on the treeView control. However if I define the Collection like this

```
 private Collection<string> _myList;
    public Collection<string> MyList 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            _myList = new Collection<string>();
            _myList.Add("string1");
            _myList.Add("string2");
            _myList.Add("string3");
            return _myList;
        }
        set { _myList = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MyList); }
    }
```

and set the collection like this

```
 private void AddItems()
    {
        Collection<string> tempList = new Collection<string>();
        tempList.Add("string1");
        tempList.Add("string2");
        tempList.Add("string3");
        MyList = tempList;
    }
```

Then tree control does show the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial code for `AddItems` never changes the value of the property `MyList` which is a reference to a list object, it merely changes the referenced instance internally.

If you want changing collections use the [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) interface.

Answer (score 1):

The reason most likely is that the list is still the same reference. What you really want here is a [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx).